# getting Yii2 backend webroot url from frontend root?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am looking for solution how to get `Yii2` backend `webroot` path from `frontend`. I want to display image which is inside `web/uploads` in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your frontend config/main.php You can do it add a urlManagerBackend entry ..

```
'components' => [
    //can name it whatever you want as it is custom
    'urlManagerBackend' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => 'mybackendend/absolutepath/uploads/',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
],
```

and the you can refer to this in this way

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->baseUrl;
```

You can [see this form yii2 forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/62713-how-to-use-backend-images-in-frontend/)

Comment: i am getting error while using the above given code by you- error is Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::urlManagerBackend

Comment: There was an error I have update the answer.. Check or show me yoyr components urlManagerBackend please.

Comment: sorry i am not getting backend urlManagerBackend configuration in frontend views

Comment: If  my answer is right please mark it as accepted ..